# How to get touch position in a listview?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the position when the listview is touched such that when touched at a specific position, it should show a toast.

Here is my touch listener for listview :-

```
customListFilter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            int actionX = (int) event.getX();
            int actionY = (int) event.getY();
            int extraTapArea = 13;
            int x = (int) (actionX + extraTapArea);
            int y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);
            x = getWidth() - x;

            if(x <= 0){
                x += extraTapArea;
            }
            if (y <= 0)
                y = actionY;                

            if ((actionX,actionY).contains(x, y)) {
                // Show Toast Here
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please help me with my logic.
Basically if i touch the right or left side in a listview but not the middle part, it should show a toast

Comment: please do comment if you downvote with the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like the following :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
customListFilter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            int actionX = (int) event.getX();
            int actionY = (int) event.getY();

        int middlePoint = width/2 ; 

        if(actionX >middlePoint ){
            // you are touching the right side
        }else if (actionX <middlePoint ){
            // you are touching the left side
        }

                        return false;
        }
    });
```

and give me some feedback

Hope that helps .

Comment: Awesome Answer . Thanks. Tell me this, is my question that bad to get downvoted ?

Comment: its not me who did the downvote , so i dont know :)
and you are welcome :)